# How play video after click on a Button?

Tags: android

i want play video in thextureView after a button clicked but its not work, while my code work if i put it in onCreate method, it's true that i cant play it if i don't create it in onCreate?

i want play video in thextureView after a button clicked but its not work, while my code work if i put it in onCreate method, it's true that i cant play it if i don't create it in onCreate?

i want play video in thextureView after a button clicked but its not work, while my code work if i put it in onCreate method, it's true that i cant play it if i don't create it in onCreate? 
this is my code:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextureView mPreview;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener surfaceTextureListener;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    mPreview = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    //I COMMENT THIS PART ANDE RUN IT IN onClick BUT ITS NOT WORK :/
    //        surfaceTextureListener=new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    //            @Override
    //            public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    //                Surface s = new Surface(surface);
    //                try {
    //                    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    //                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("/storage/emulated/0/dff91403790b4f1702f4cda4b83626fa.mp4");
    //                    mMediaPlayer.setSurface(s);
    //                    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    //                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
   ...
    //        mPreview.setSurfaceTextureListener(surfaceTextureListener);
    //
}
//EDITED
public void onClick(View v){
    //THIS PART NOT WORK
    surfaceTextureListener=new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            Surface s = new Surface(surface);
            try {
                mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("/storage/emulated/0/dff91403790b4f1702f4cda4b83626fa.mp4");
                mMediaPlayer.setSurface(s);
                mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
              mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                mMediaPlayer.release();
                mMediaPlayer = null;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        }
    };
    mPreview.setSurfaceTextureListener(surfaceTextureListener);

}
}
```

help me please?

Comment: onClick is this method declared in XML

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting onClick in xml attribute? If yes, This is happening because you have declared that method in xml with onclick attribute. When you declare that with onclick attribute in xml You must have public modifier in java code to work.
replace your code

```
void onClick(View v)
```

with below line

```
public void onClick(View v){
```

hope that helps you.

Comment: tanks, but no this is a sample of my code that i have is not real my code, and alse with true onCreate its not work.